# Any widgets in flutter allow me to have a profile picture but if they don't have one the initials show instead?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Im trying to make a flutter app for HR and for my employee's section I need to have it so that their initials are shown if a profile picture is unavailable is there a widget which allows me to do this?

Below is an example of what im trying to achieve

[image: This is an Example of what im trying to achieve]

Comment: `if (hasPicture) Image(...) else Text(...)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it with CachedNetworkImage

```
CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: "http://myimage...",
            placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Text("my initials here"),
         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Do Something Like This, but first Need to check for Image thats depends on how you are managing data and then
_isImageAvailable ? ProfileImage() : Text(Name)

Comment: I explained the Logic , if You Show me Your Code then will Provide a Complete Solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          child: hasImage
              ? Image.network(
                  imageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                )
              : Center(
                  child: Text('$nameInitial'),
                ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: can you explain the logic?

Comment: if hasImage, it will display the image. If no image it will display the nameInitial.
name initial you need to find out based on your logic. e.g. take first character from both first and last name, or only first character of first name etc.
Here I only add the code, because I thought you are new with flutter. If you check the widget tree you can change background color, border radius, size of the image container etc. from this code.